# How to remove Scroll bar from Accordian?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true ,
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true,

            header: ".accordion-header"
        }).sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: ".accordion-header",
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                ui.item.children( ".accordion-header" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
            }
        });
});
```

I want to remove scroll from accordian..it's not working..

Answer (score 1):

Setting heightStyle: "content" allows the accordion panels to keep their native height

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this: with `clearStyle` and `heightStyle`

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
             heightStyle: "content",
             collapsible: true ,
             autoHeight: false,
             clearStyle: true,   
        });
```